# Is it possible to "shrink" a PdfPtable?

Tags: itext

I am currently working with Itextsharp and I have some trouble with PDfPtables.
Sometimes they get too big for a page and, when added to a document, are broken up on multiple pages.
Sadly ths rational behviour is not acceptable for some of my superiors - they keep insisting that the table shall be "shrunk" to a page. Is there a way to achieve this? There are some tantalizing hints that i could be possible - but hints are all that i have.

What is the alternative? Perhaps I could delete the fat table from the document and build the table again with smaller Fonts and Cells, but that would be very cumberosme - I would prefer to "zoom out", in lack of a better word.

My current code:

```
Dim test As PdfContentByte = mywriter.DirectContent
Dim templ = test.CreateTemplate(mywriter.PageSize.Width, mywriter.PageSize.Height)
Table.WriteSelectedRows(0, Table.Rows.Count - 1, 0.0F, mywriter.PageSize.Height, templ)
Dim myimage = Image.GetInstance(templ)
'   myimage.ScaleAbsolute(mywriter.PageSize.Width, mywriter.PageSize.Height)
```

would scaleabsolute be necessary?
    myimage.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0)
    test.AddImage(myimage)

This code puts something one the page, but it has the height of the page and the width is about a quarter of the page - wi will try to find the bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the table and define a 'total width'. As soon as iText knows the width of the table, you can calculate the height of all the rows. Once you know the height, you can check:

1. Does the table fit the page? Just add it as is. Maybe using `WriteSelectedRows` if you don't want to take any page margins into account.
2. Isn't there enough space on the page? Add the table to a `PdfTemplate` (there's more than one way to do this), wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image`. Scale the image, and add it to the document.

Comment: Thank, that is the first comprehensive answer I've heard so far!

Comment: I have a question: What do you mean with "and image"? My code so far is above...thx!

Comment: It was a typo. I see one error in your code: when creating the template you use PageSize.Height as height. This doesn't solve your problem. You should calculate the height (as is done in http://1t3xt.be/?04f ) of the table and use that height. You need that same value as Y-offset in WriteSelectedRows. Also, it's OK to use -1 instead of Table.Rows.Count - 1. Using -1 will draw all rows.

Comment: I was unable to find table.gettotalheight as a method - I will try to use CalculateHeights.

Comment: I'm used to working with iText, hence the get in the method names. You should drop the get as is done in this C# version of the example I referred to: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter04&ex=TableHeight