# Preventing iTextSharp from putting a page break in the middle of a PdfPTable?

Tags: pagination, itext

I'm using iTextSharp v5.3 to build a PDF with one or more tables that are have the same cells but can vary in height due to dynamic content.  Currently, if a `PdfPTable` is too large to fit on the current page the table is broken and the remaining cell data ends up on the next page.  Is there a way I can tell iTextSharp that if the table won't fit, to put the **whole thing** on the next page?

[image: Bad Table Break]

I've tried messing around with `SplitRows` and `SplitLate` but they don't have the desired effect.  I have also tried to do some calculations after adding the `PdfPTable` to the document but can't figure out how to get the "cursor position" on the page.  Do I need to track the current page's height in my loop and do all of the calculations myself?

Comment: Add the record templates as a new pdfptable (each cell of the main table, should contain a pdfptabe. Now SplitRows and SplitLate should work based on the whole object's height).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask the table for its total height. This is done like this: `table.TotalHeight`

If the height is 0, make sure you've defined the width first: iText can't calculate the width if it doesn't know the available width to render the table.

Once you have the height, ask the writer for the vertical position: `writer.GetVerticalPosition(true)`

As you probably know, the Y coordinate is 0 at the bottom of the page. If the vertical position minus the total height of the page exceeds the margin size, you know that the table won't fit, and you can trigger a new page.

Comment: how do i get the "total height of the page"?

Comment: You define that height yourself when creating the document object. Just subtract the margins. By default,  an A4 page is created (842) and the margins are 36. So the default height is 770 unless you've defined another page size and margins.

Comment: You'll have to explain why `GetVerticalPosition` isn't working for you. It works for the people who approved and voted for this answer. Also: the comment section isn't the place to post such an additional question. Create a new question and phrase it in a way that is different from "it doesn't work". See http://lowagie.com/doesntwork

Answer (score 9):

You can also use:

```
tableName.KeepTogether = true;
```

Comment: much better then calculating heights.. just what I was looking for!

Comment: This has to be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bruno Lowagie has pointed out the correct solution - I would like to add the possibility to shrink a table to a page, even when it is too big.
Look here: [Is it possible to "shrink" a PdfPtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970736/is-it-possible-to-shrink-a-pdfptable)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the "correct" way, but you can wrap your table in a single-cell container table. A single cell can't be split in half.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the following:
    PdfPTable ContainerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    ContainerTable .WidthPercentage = 100;
    PdfPCell ContainerTableCell = new PdfPCell();
    // Add your stuff to the ContainerTableCell.

Comment: For goodness' sake. Comments can only be edit for 5mins? 

I can't format multi-line code in here, so [see this gist instead](https://gist.github.com/Krummelz/ba0f9711b78c96e3511a1bb5b1938090)